# Redirect web service request to another address

Tags: web-services, spring

I have `Spring WS` which handle all kind of request in `spring-ws-servlet.xml` context:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Is there a way to create a policy where specific request will be redirected to address i want? for example when someone request for address `localhost:8080/MyProject/someofrequest.asmx` my `web.xml` will redirect this request to `localhost:8080/MyProject/HandleMessage` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution would be to create a very simple servlet that will redirect requests with the pattern `*.asmx` to your `/HandleMessage` action:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.x.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>redirect</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.asmx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Servlet code:

```
public class RedirectServlet extends HttpServlet{
        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
              response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/MyProject/HandleMessage");
        }
}
```